# Storing / Accessing Configuration Data for an ASP.NET MVC Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, metadata

I'm working on a large form in an ASP.NET MVC commercial enterprise application that needs to be configurable.  The form has around 100 possible fields, but since each corporate customer only needs a small subset of these I need to be able to configure the visibility of each form field.  The configuration is easy -- I'll just store a list of visible fields in the database -- but I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to control the visibility of each field in the view on the front end.

I've built some custom HTML helpers to render the form in the view.  I have a helper to render the form which will just iterate over the data model properties and render inputs for the fields that have been configured to be visible.  The thing I can't figure out is where do I store the visibility configuration?  It seems more like metadata than model data, but I'm not sure where/how I would store/access it.

Where do I put the form configuration data, and how should I access it from my html helpers?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a ViewModel which contains your current model as a property and an additional new property (generic list possibly) of items that need to be shown.

By default ensure that non of the form fields are visible then loop through the generic list in your view firing the appropriate methods/extension/helper to turn on the fields in the list.